# Iterate print for each line in output

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, ksh

I want to print `uvuveve` at finish each line, for each output into while statement, as below:

```
var1;var2;uvuveve
var1;var2;uvuveve
var1;var2;uvuveve
var1;var2;uvuveve
var1;var2;uvuveve
```

This is my code:

```
var1="somedata..."
var2="anotherdata..."
while read -u3 w1; read -u4 w2; do
echo "$w1;$w2" >> $file
done 3<<< "$var1" 4<<<"$var2"
```

var1, var2 print multiple occurrences of a file, so there are many outputs by these variables. I tried to add `uvuveve` word like this way:

```
var1="somedata..."
var2="anotherdata..."
string="uvuveve"
while read -u3 w1; read -u4 w2; read -u5 w3; do
echo "$w1;$w2;$w3" >> $file
done 3<<< "$var1" 4<<<"$var2" 5<<<"$string"
```

Essentially, I need a print of the word in each line, for each occurrence founded.

**Adding Details:**

`Var1` & `var2` retrieve lines of occurrences that a file contains, and then put into variables

Literally the lines are:

```
var1=$(grep -A12 -B12 "$tofind" $findlogs | grep Date | cut -c 51-65 | sed -e 's! !/!g')
var2=$(grep -A12 -B12 "$tofind" $findlogs | grep Date | cut -c 67-71 | sed -e 's/://g')
```

Comment: Does replacing `echo "$w1;$w2;$w3"` with `echo "$w1;$w2;$string"` solve the problem?  If not, please provide enough input data (and corresponding desired output) so that we can understand what you are actually trying to do.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Adding the $w3 varaible (string) only add one time the string.

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggested that you change the code as per my comment.

Comment: Does the data in your two variables `var1` and `var2` come from a file? Could you give a real example of input and output?

Comment: @Kusalananda here goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just have plain text in variables, redirecting them into a while-read loop seems ridiculously over-complicated.

What's wrong with

```
var1="somedata..."
var2="anotherdata..."
string="uvuveve"

echo "$var1;$var2;$string"
# or
printf '%s;%s;%s\n' "$var1" "$var2" "$string"
```

---

If you actually have files, then you do need a loop. If we have

```
$ cat file1
a
b
c
$ cat file2
1
2
3
```

then

```
string="uvuveve"
while IFS= read -r -u3 a; read -r -u4 b; do 
    printf '%s;%s;%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$string"
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

```
a;1;uvuveve
b;2;uvuveve
c;3;uvuveve
```

---

Going back to your edit: use [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)s

```
# don't repeat yourself
dates=$(grep -A12 -B12 "$tofind" $findlogs | grep Date)
string="uvuveve"
while IFS= read -r -u3 a; read -r -u4 b; do 
    printf '%s;%s;%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$string"
done 3< <(echo "$dates" | cut -c 51-65 | sed -e 's! !/!g') \
     4< <(echo "$dates" | cut -c 67-71 | sed -e 's/://g')
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS=$'\n'; var1=( $( ... your command here ... ) );
IFS=$'\n'; var2=( $( ... your command here ... ) );

for i in ${!var1[@]}; do
  echo ${arr1[$i]};${arr2[$i]};uvuveve
done
```

It assumes that `var1` and `var2` have the same amount of lines.

Basically:

1. We turn your command into a variable that is an array. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768435/701263)
2. Then we iterate the array ([source](https://medium.com/@robaboukhalil/the-weird-wondrous-world-of-bash-arrays-a86e5adf2c69)) adding the variables together and your extra string.

Comment: I have other script with arrays, and your solution was useful. Thanks, Kyle!

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below command

```
$ j="praveen"
$ k="ajay"
$ m="abhi"

$ awk -v j="$j" -v k="$k" -v m="$m" '{print j"\n"k"\n"m;exit}'
praveen
ajay
abhi
```

Comment: KIndly mention reason for downvote